# Issue in running Fortran in jupyter notebook in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, fortran, jupyter-kernel

I am able to work with Fortran kernel in jupyter-notebook in the browser but getting issue in vscode

I could select Fortran as kernel option in vscode but giving this error
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sChEh.png)
where should be the appropriate kernel.json file for fortran here or there should be some other solution?

I tried to run fortran code in jupyter notebook inside vscode but getting issue

Comment: Please post the error as text [in addition to the picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). You can [edit] and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. While you're editing, you should set a more specific title; like, what issue exactly? Mentioning "insecure location" could help. See [ask] for tips on that and more.

Comment: Did you try following the instructions in the error message?  If so, what results?  In general, what have tried to fix the problem and what were the results?

Comment: Please, never put important info, like an error message, into a picture. Always copy and paste it as text. This is really very important. The error message must be visible and searchable, so that people with a similar problem can find the answers to their problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.